# After upgrade, "everything" starts to segfault

Tags: ubuntu, upgrade, segmentation-fault

I just upgraded my Ubuntu 20.04.

After the upgrade I suddenly started to see a massive amounts of segfaults like this:

```
[   87.157912] perl[5442]: segfault at 0 ip 0000556a510d9f05 sp 00007fff768ae410 error 6 in perl[556a510d5000+16a000]
[   87.157919] Code: be 08 00 00 00 48 c1 f9 03 48 8d 6c 09 02 48 81 fd 00 08 00 00 48 0f 47 e8 48 89 ef e8 54 cc ff ff 48 8d 54 e8 f8 48 8d 48 20 <48> 89 10 49 8b 54 24 08 48 89 50 08 49 89 44 24 08 48 8b 10 48 c1
[   87.158481] perl[5504]: segfault at 0 ip 000055db4eb74f05 sp 00007fff87b13870 error 6 in perl[55db4eb70000+16a000]
[   87.158489] Code: be 08 00 00 00 48 c1 f9 03 48 8d 6c 09 02 48 81 fd 00 08 00 00 48 0f 47 e8 48 89 ef e8 54 cc ff ff 48 8d 54 e8 f8 48 8d 48 20 <48> 89 10 49 8b 54 24 08 48 89 50 08 49 89 44 24 08 48 8b 10 48 c1
[   87.613155] perl[5509]: segfault at 8 ip 00005597f965f58a sp 00007ffdc4c26d60 error 4 in perl[5597f95f1000+16a000]
[   87.613166] Code: 00 00 00 48 8b 06 0f b7 40 20 66 0f 1f 44 00 00 66 85 c0 0f 84 aa 0e 00 00 83 e8 01 0f b7 c0 8d 34 18 49 8b 46 18 48 8d 14 f0 <8b> 02 85 c0 0f 85 8c 00 00 00 44 89 22 49 8b 46 18 89 da 83 44 d0
```

The problem is not limited to `perl`, so I reckon something went wrong during my upgrade.

I did a memory test and found a bad memory module. This could explain the segfaults.

I have now removed the bad memory module, and the system passes a memory test.

But the problem is still there.

I then figured: Maybe libc (or similar) got corrupted by the memory module during upgrade. So I ran:

```
debsums | grep -v OK
```

and it shows no errors.

What would cause the segfaults?

*Edit:*

I have forced reinstallation of libc6 and libc6++. This did not fix the issue.

The good part is, that I can provoke the error by putting the system under heavy load. When that happens, programs will start complaining out of memory (yet there is 80 GB swap free) and 'xmalloc failed'.

One explanation would be if the kernel has a flipped bit in some `malloc` routine.

During the upgrade a new initrd (and kernel?) was built using `update-initramfs`. If we assume some part of this has been done with the faulty RAM and thus I have a kernel with few bit errors in, how can I rebuild this cleanly? I.e. how do I `make clean` before running `update-initramfs`, so all input to this would be pristine?

Edit 2:

When I put the machine under heavy load, programs like Xorg and Firefox will crash. This behavior would not be surprising if I was running low on virtual memory, but there is 80 GB free.

Running `strace` forces all the heavy load through a single `strace` command, and then the segfaults do not happen.

Edit 3:

I can no longer reliably reproduce the error. It is not gone, but happens much less frequently.

Comment: Use `strace` to follow an executable until it segfaults. That will give you an idea what the executable is doing right up until the boom.

Comment: Reseat all memory modules, run extensive memory tests again. This looks hardware related.

Comment: @Freddy Done. Thrice. It passes all memory tests.